# Boostrap 3: list on multiple columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I guys, I'm working on a web application and I'm using Bootstrap 3.
I have a list of items: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, L, M

I would like to represent the list as follows:

For large devices:
A C E G I M
B D F H L

For medium or large devices:
A E I
B F L
C G M
D H

For small devices:
A G
B H
C I
D L
E M
F

For extra small devices:
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
L
M

Comment: A bad solution is to render the list 4 times (splitting it and using more than one ul element each time) and use BS 3 helper classes to show the desired one according to the break point.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with fewer breakpoints than you've asked for (3 vs 4), you could do this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">A</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">D</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">E</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">F</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">G</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">H</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12">J</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">K</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">L</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The reason I suggest 3 vs 4 breakpoints is that otherwise you don't have a lowest common  number (3, in this case - 3/6/12) of elements within a column, and you'll need to find a way to make the outlier move from one column to another (i.e. 3/4/6/12 gets messy where 3 meets 4). It is possible to overcome, with divs set to `hidden-*` + `clearfix` interspersed, but it's very complex, and possibly not worth it.

NOTE: Normally you would want to put `.row`s between your nested columns, but in this case it also complicates things, so you may want some custom CSS to negate the compounding padding that nesting creates, but you may also be fine with it...

PS - bootply is flaky right now so can't save my DEMO, but it works, really!

Comment: Thanks! It works (a close div tag is missing in your code). Unfortunately it is not possible to use the UL element and it is not as flexible as I need.

Probably the best way to do that is to use the nwq CSS3 multi column layout, but it is not supported in IE8 & IE9 (found on http://caniuse.com/#search=column layout)

Answer (score 0):

You should read on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

`<div class="col-lg-*></div>` for large screen
`<div class="col-md-*></div>` for medium screen
`<div class="col-sm-*></div>` for small screen
`<div class="col-xs-*></div>` for extra small screen

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I already read the documentation. The list must be read vertically, not horizontally (look at my question carefully).

Comment: Mauro isn't misunderstanding your question, you're misunderstanding his suggestion. What he suggest WILL render the list vertically, if you use it properly, and add a few helper classes.